# Golang IPv6 server

Tags: go, ipv6

How to create ipv6 server. ipv4 server looks like

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func h(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Test")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", h)
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

but how to listen ipv6 in 80 port

Comment: That's all. It will listen on ipv6 if ipv6 is supported on the host.

Comment: @Adrian I tried today in scaleway and through GCP load balancer, but but when I open ipv6 address in browser I saw nothing, if I open ipv4 page shows fine

Comment: Then something somewhere doesn't have ipv6 enabled, but if I run that exact code locally (my machine supports v6) I get a v6 listener.

Comment: @Adrian you access ipv6 in browser? how it looks, like http://[fe80::a96c:c899:ea0a:77d9%6] ?

Comment: I can access localhost by http://[::1] yes.

Comment: Google Compute doesn't support IPv6. And Scaleway requires that you turn it on separately for each individual instance, which is really annoying.

Comment: @MichaelHampton in CGP i've try through load balancer which support ipv6. in scaleway i set enable ipv6 when create instance, or i need something else?

Comment: The GCP load balancer terminates IPv6, but all communication within Google Cloud Platform, including to your instances, is IPv4.

Comment: @ChunkCoder I have the same problem.  Did you figure out the issue?

Answer (score 4):

It already is listening on ipv6 (as well as ipv4).

```
func ListenAndServe(addr string, handler Handler) error {
    server := &Server{Addr: addr, Handler: handler}
    return server.ListenAndServe()
}

// ListenAndServe listens on the TCP network address srv.Addr and then
// calls Serve to handle requests on incoming connections.
// Accepted connections are configured to enable TCP keep-alives.
// If srv.Addr is blank, ":http" is used.
// ListenAndServe always returns a non-nil error.
func (srv *Server) ListenAndServe() error {
    addr := srv.Addr
    if addr == "" {
        addr = ":http"
    }
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return srv.Serve(tcpKeepAliveListener{ln.(*net.TCPListener)})
}
```

If you want to *only* listen on ipv6, you can do

```
func ListenAndServe(addr string, handler Handler) error {
    srv := &http.Server{Addr: addr, Handler: handler}
    addr := srv.Addr
    if addr == "" {
        addr = ":http"
    }
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp6", addr) // <--- tcp6 here
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return srv.Serve(tcpKeepAliveListener{ln.(*net.TCPListener)})
}
```

Comment: No need to go through all that, you can specify an address to listen on. If you specify a v4 address you get a v4 listener, a v6 address you get a v6 listener.

Comment: You can, but the docs specifically recommend against it: "The address can use a host name, but this is not recommended, because it will create a listener for at most one of the host's IP addresses."

Comment: I didn't suggest using a host name.

Comment: ah, I misunderstood.